# Marshaling items in lists using flask restful

Tags: flask, marshalling, flask-restful

I am writing a [Flask-RESTFUL](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) resource. It returns a `Model` object called `DocumentSet` with the following structure:

```
DocumentSet:
id: int
documents: list of Document
```

`Document` is another `Model` object with the following structure:

```
Document:
id: int
...other fields...
```

I want to write a `@marshal_with` decorator that returns the `DocumentSet` id along with a list of the `Document` ids like so:

```
{
    id: 5,
    document_ids: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I've been banging my head against the [output marshaling syntax](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/fields.html) to no avail. Some of the things I've tried:

```
{'id': fields.Integer, 'document_ids':fields.List(fields.Integer, attribute='documents.id')}
{'id': fields.Integer, 'document_ids':fields.List(fields.Nested({'id':fields.Integer}), attribute='documents')}
```

What's the magic incantation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic incantation is

```
{'id': fields.Integer, 'name': fields.String, 'document-ids':{'id': fields.Integer}}
```

It was right there in the "[Complex Structures](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/fields.html#complex-structures)" paragraph in the documentation.